# Не работает гамбургер меню на мобильном Safari

Tags: html, css, wordpress, ios, safari

Не работает гамбургер меню в мобильной версии Safari на сайте https://drummondhearing.co.uk/

Пробовал добавлять cursor:pointer, но не помогает. Пожалуйста, помогите найти проблему.

Comment: а что, `cursor:pointer` помогал когда-либо?

Comment: На просторах интернета это преподносилось, как решение(

Comment: Уберите фиксированую высоту у `mkdf-mobile-header-inner` и добавьте ее `mkdf-mobile-header-holder`

Comment: Алексей, спасибо вам больше, за то, что уделили внимание моей проблеме, но, к сожалению, не помогло. Однако, я правда очень вам благодарен

Comment: Уверены что убрали высоту у mkdf-mobile-header-inner ? Потому что у меня все работает.

Comment: Для наилучшего и скорейшего решения вашего вопроса рекомендую вам привести здесь ваш рабочий код. Так будет намного легче помочь вам. :)

Comment: Алексей, простите мне мою невнимательность, вы были абсолютно правы. Там действительно дело в фиксированной высоте. Спасибо вам большое за помощь, вы наверняка не представляете как меня выручили. Всего вам самого наилучшего.